# Fast question, IF statement doesn't seem to work for while loop on disabling a element

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

As you can see in the code below, i want to disable the MINUS button of a quantity product when the value is `if(inputVal == '1') {`

The weird thing is that the ALERT works and counts correctly if there are 2 products with a quantity of ONE(`inputVal`), but the IF statement seems to apply every MINUS button ON disabling it when it should only disable the MINUS button if the quantity is 1(as the if statement say's).

I don't understand why it disables all the MINUS buttons while they don't have a quantity of 1.

Here come's my code:

**//JqueryCode**

```
$('.update-quantity-section').each(function () {
    var inputVal = $(this).find('.cart-quantity').val();
    console.log(inputVal);
    if(inputVal == '1') {
        alert('disabled');
        $('.update-quantity').addClass('disableClick');
    } else {
        $('.update-quantity').removeClass('disableClick');
    }
});
```

**//CSS code**

```
.disableClick{
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

**//While loop in PHP/HTML**

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    extract($row);
    echo "<div class='col-md-2 update-quantity-section' style='text-align:center;'>";
               echo "<div class='quantity'>
             <div class='minus'><a class='change-quantity update-quantity' data-id='{$id}' data-multi='-1'>-</a></div>
             <div class='sp-input'>
               <input type='text' class='quantity-input cart-quantity' value='{$quantity}' />
             </div>
             <div class='plus'><a class='change-quantity update-quantity' data-id='{$id}' data-multi='1'>+</a></div>
           </div>";
    echo "</div>";
}
```

I searched alot but i don't know what to search for for this problem. Because it confuses me that the ALERT works and counts they elements good which have NUMBER 1 quantity. But the addclass and removeclass doesn't work.

Thanks for your time, i appreciate it.

Comment: So stop for a second and look at what you are doing.  You are doing a contextual lookup for the cart-quantity in each section, but you **are not** doing a contextual lookup for the update-quantity to add the class to.  You are doing global lookups there.

Comment: Please dont use `extract()` it is a great way to get yourself in a real mess

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Like: is that a PHP problem, a jQuery problem, an HTML problem, or a CSS problem? I'd asume that the chance is pretty low that all four techniques are involved

Comment: @Taplar You are right, i was close. I was already copying the `this find (` But i had typed in i a wrong order or something. But yeah your right. I need to work on stopping for a minute and look at it. When i want to solve something i go BAM BAM BAM BAM in my head  XD :P

Comment: @RiggsFolly No? i didn't know about that? But without extracting i cant GET the variables right? Like `{$id}`. How does it work without `extract()`?

Comment: @NicoHaase I debugged it using Jquery and it was a Jquery problem. Thanks for your answer and time

Comment: Without extract `$row[id]`

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks for your answer and time. I will do that if you say so, have to change it on the whole project though. If i may ask why is using extract() bad? How can it get in a mess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.update-quantity').addClass('disableClick');
$('.update-quantity').removeClass('disableClick');
```

This is adding/removing the class every element with the `.update-quantity` class, you need to do:

```
$(this).find('.update-quantity').addClass('disableClick');
```

and you can change:

```
if(inputVal == '1') {
    alert('disabled');
    $('.update-quantity').addClass('disableClick');
} else {
    $('.update-quantity').removeClass('disableClick');
}
```

to

```
 $(this).find('.update-quantity').toggleClass('disableClick', inputVal == '1');
```

Comment: Thanks for your time i appreciate it. It behaves weird on loading of the page. If it is 1 already it the MINUS is blocked. But if i then press PLUS it goes up and if i press minus it is also disabled. And if the quantity is on load 2 then the MINUS button never gets disabled.

I tried to copy the code and make a click event out of it with the MINUS class but that works weird also, i have to double click the minus button for it to work, i dont know. 

Am still testing it..

Comment: Now it works, i copied the code and made 1 code to execute when the document is ready and 1 code when i click the minus button. Now it works. Thanks for your help.